# Как правильно делать сокращение из «пожалуйста»?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно делать сокращение из *пожалуйста*?

а) ПЖ

б) пж

в) п. ж.

г) п/ж

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%96#:~:text=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0,%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%A1%D0%9C%D0%98%C2%BB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%96#:%7E:text=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0,%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%A1%D0%9C%D0%98%C2%BB)

Answer (score 2):

Обычно мы используем слово "пожалуйста", чтобы показать (проявить, выразить, продемонстрировать) свое уважение (предупредительность, почтительность) к собеседнику, показать свою воспитанность (деликатность, вежливость).
Ключевое слово здесь – "показать", поэтому (на мой взгляд) все сокращения (в тексте) слова «пожалуйста» неуместны. Предложенные варианты сокращенного написания служат "сокрытию" волшебного слова (по причине его избыточности, ненадобности?).
Попросите своего друга, который увлекается программированием, "повесить на пару клавиш" это слово целиком (без купюр).
В тех случаях, когда ну очень хочется щегольнуть неотекстологизмом – допустимо (по моему) использовать легко распознаваемое «пжлста».

Comment: Лучше: пжста. https://sokrasheniya.academic.ru/49912/пжлста  Кстати, это не только щегольство, но и стилистика тоже. Я использую ПЖСТА, чтобы перейти от официального стиля к дружелюбно-разговорному.

Comment: Охотно соглашаюсь с Вами, Sharon. К удивлению своему, в варианте «пжста» тоже усматриваю проявление и дружелюбия, и доверительности,  и искренности и, в какой то степени, даже незащищенности (не судите строго за...). А удивление мое ровно от того, что новый оттенок смысла достигается «упрощением» НАПИСАНИЯ исходного слова и не более того!

Comment: Спасибо! Все-таки хорошо, когда мы понимаем друг друга)